# Should I greet ciao or buongiorno when greeted by buongiorno?

Tags: word-choice, greeting

I'm now in Italy and found that a clerk sometimes use buongiorno when I entered the bar. I always use ciao when I greet, but I wonder whether it is OK to greet by ciao or should use buongiorno when I first get a greeting.

Also, should I use it apart according to the situation, for example depending on the age of the clerk and me, the type of shop (cheap bar, more upper-scale restaurants, or luxury brand, etc...), etc...?

Comment: Using *ciao* corresponds to using *tu* (informal second person), which roughly corresponds to be on first-name terms. Using *buongiorno* corresponds to using *Lei* (formal second person), which roughly corresponds to calling the other party by surname or title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use ciao in an informal situation, with your friends and with someone you know.

You use buongiorno in formal situations , when you first meet someone. It is considered a polite and respectful greet, used especially with older people.

Obviously this form can be used instead of ciao but never do the opposite or you could be considered rude.

Comment: I see, so I have been rude to the clerk... Thanks.

Comment: Well, he won’t be particularly concerned about it knowing you’re a foreigner. But remember that with people on duty is always advisable to use buongiorno.